saludos estoy aprendiendo python y estoy practicando en vs code, mi programa no quiere correr
El pequeño programa es de piedra, papel y tijera, pero cuando lo quiero correr en el terminal( vs code), me sale en amarillo la direccion del (piedra"C:User/atwor/AppData/Local/programs/Python/Python312/Python.exe") de python de la ubicacion y no entiendo mucho como lo puedo resolver. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.
este es el codigo
import random 

def get_choices():

  
    player_choice = input ("Enter a choice ( rock, paper, scissor:)")
  
    option = ["rock", "paper","scissor"]
    computer_choice = random.choice(option)
   
    choices = {"player": player_choice, "computer": computer_choice}
 
    choice =  get_choices()
    print = (choices)


Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Agregué lo necesario para publicar el código, pero ahora no estoy seguro de que esa sea tu indentación original, y en python eso es muy importante. Por favor re-edita la pregunta si la indentación no es la correcta. Observa que el código está entre triple ticks (```), manten eso para que se publique bien. Si esa es tu indentación, el programa no hace nada, pues no tiene nada en el programa principal.

Tu código tiene tres problemas, pero nada tiene que ver con el "error" que mencionas: 1. Tu función no retorna nada, necesitas agregar return choices al final de la misma. 2.  Lo que comenta Candid Moe, debes llamar a la función fuera de ella, la linea choices =  get_choices() debe ir fuera de la función (al mismo nivel de sangrado que def get_choices()), puede que solo sea un problema de formato al pegar el código aquí. 3. No es print = (choices), sino print(choices).

En cuanto al tema de "lo que marca en amarillo" deberias intentar ser más especifico,  quizás una captura de pantalla ayude, pero corrigiendo lo mencionado no sería problema de código, sino del IDE, de su configuración o de la instalación de Python.

saludos a todos, muchas gracias por su ayuda, corregi esos erroes y adicional tenia sintaxis tenia "choices" y en otro "choice" y ahora corre bien! tenia la colocacion erronea y ese otro detalle!

Haz definido una función, pero no la llamas en ninguna parte.
También puedes mejorar el código eliminando variables intermedias innecesarias:
import random


def get_choices():
    player_choice = input("Enter a choice ( rock, paper, scissor:)")
    computer_choice = random.choice(["rock", "paper", "scissor"])
    return {"player": player_choice, "computer": computer_choice}

print(get_choices())

produce:
Enter a choice ( rock, paper, scissor:)rock
{'player': 'rock', 'computer': 'scissor'}

Process finished with exit code 0

